How to show an entire image for a launcher icon in Android
I have the following png file house.png in the drawable folder of my Android app

I would like to use it as a launcher icon and thus I use it in this XML layout file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/house"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</adaptive-icon>

with ic_launcher_background
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>

Unfortunately, just a part of the figure is shown as you can see here in the screenshot:
. Also when installing it on a real device, only a part of the image is shown. I tried to decrease the resolution, but this did not help as the image is then just being displayed with lower quality (less pixels).
How can I use the entire image as a launcher icon?

You need to leave a margin in your icon image, as Android uses adaptive icons which can change shape in various situations.
You can learn about this and find the guidelines here.

@MaxAleander: Thanks Max for your answer and the link. Actually, I don't understand how to make these adaptive icons. First of all I don't want to use an adaptive icon but just a plain icon for launching the app. Moreover, in your posted link it is written that I should make the icon  48 x 48 dp to 66 × 66 dp. How can I do that? Where can I specify the dp in the icon?

Unfortunately they don't give you a choice, all the launcher icons are adaptive now. dp means "density independent pixels" and is a method of dealing with different screen sizes. If you feel that it is too complicated, just think of it as a ratio: 48/66 is 0.77. So leave a blank margin around your icon that is about a quarter the width of the image.
